# PowerShell TFS REST-API object loop advise

Tags: powershell

I have a piece of code that i managed to get working, but i feel that it can be written a lot easier. Im new with PowerShell and am trying to understand it better. I have a double foreach below to get the key and value out of the PSCustomObject that comes out of the TFS REST-API call.

For some reason im doing 2 loops, but i dont understand why this is required.

A sample of the contents of $nameCap.userCapabilities is

```
Name1  Name2
-----    -----
Value1   Value2
```

So basically i want to loop over the "name/value pairs" and get their values.

What can i do better ?

```
$uri = "$tfsUri/_apis/distributedtask/pools/$global:agentPoolId/agents?api-version=3.0-preview&includeCapabilities=true"    
$result =  (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials).value | select name, userCapabilities, systemCapabilities

    #Loop over all agents and their capablities
    foreach ($nameCap in $result)   
    {
        $capabilityNamesList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

        #Loop over all userCapabilities and store their names
        @($nameCap.userCapabilities) | %{
            $current_Cap = $_
            $req_cap_exists = $false

            Get-Member -MemberType Properties -InputObject $current_Cap | %{
                $temp_NAME = $_.Name 
                $temp_Value = Select-Object -InputObject $current_Cap -ExpandProperty $_.Name

                [void]$capabilityNamesList.Add($temp_NAME) 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean if you just need the Name and value, like userCapabilities, then just select for it.

so:

```
$result | select Name,userCapabilites
```

And if it doesn't give you a table automatically, then `| ft -force`